# Compare the key of a JSON Object to a String

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to compare the key of a `JSON Object` to a `String` to assess whether or not my `JSON Object` contains the specified value at that key before continue processing.
Here is a sample of the `String` .

`{'type':'Layout','subType':'REPEATGRID','pgRef':'.pySections(1).pySectionBody(1).pyTable.pyRows(1).pyCells(3).pySections(1)'}`

Here is the code I used to perform the evaluation. Let's assume the `String` above is store in a variable `str`

```
jsonString = str.replaceAll("\'", "\"");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
System.out.println((String) jsonObject.get("subType") == "REPEATGRID");
```

The code above returns **false** while the statement `System.out.println((String) jsonObject.get("subType"));` returns **REPEATGRID**

Why is the evaluation returning false?
How can I properly evaluate this situation?

PS: I am using `org.json.simple` library.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `equals()` instead of `==`

```
   System.out.println((String) jsonObject.get("subType").equals("REPEATGRID"));
```

Further more,to aovid NullPointerException,you can improve as above:

```
   System.out.println("REPEATGRID".equals((String) jsonObject.get("subType")));
```

Comment: I did, but my reputation is under 15